# Proving an equality between two sums

Tags: linear-algebra

Please, help me to prove that

$\sum_{k=1}^m a_{kj}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_{ik}w_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^m\left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{kj}\right)w_i$

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in what you write ; check

Comment: Draw an nxn matrix where the entry in row $i$ column $k$ is $a_{kj}b_{ik}w_i$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you correct the expression (limits of the sums), this is basically

$$A(Bw) = (AB)w,$$

written element-wise ($A$ and $B$ are matrices, and $w$ is a vector, all of the appropriate dimensions).

You can put $a_{kj}$ in the inner sum, then swap two sums, and then get $w_i$ out of the inner sum. Try it yourself, and if you fail, write what you did and we'll help you.

Comment: Good evening, Vedran. I checked the expression. It is as in the book. $A:E\rightarrow F$, and $B:F\rightarrow G$ are linear transforms, $U={u_1,...,u_p}\subset E$, $V={v_1,...,v_n}\subset F$, $W={w_1,...,w_m}\subset G$ are basis, $a\in M(nxp)$ is the matrix of A in the basis U,V and $b\in M(mxn)$ is the matrix of B in the basis V,W.

Comment: Check the limits on sums. Your $k$ is always the first index in $a$ and a second index in $b$, but on the left hand side of your expression $k$ goes $1$ through $m$, while on the right hand side it $1$ through $n$. Your $i$ behaves similarly.